# Sum value in cells that contain both number and text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, google-sheets-filter

I need to sum a range of cells with text in them.

Example:

```
a1= "25,00 market"  b1="24,00 credit card" c1="75,11 food"
a2= "10,00 sweets"  b2="9,00 market"       c2="24,00 keyboard"
```

I want to sum all the numbers in cells that contain "market" in this range. Something like:

```
 =SUMIF(a1:c2; "*market*"; a1:c2 )
```

But this always returns the value `0`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the issue is that only you see the numbers  - sheet doesn't. sheet sees only text so you need to extract those (visual) numbers to become actual ones and then work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### US syntax:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER({A1:A;B1:B;C1:C}, 
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*market*", {A1:A;B1:B;C1:C}))), "[0-9]*\,[0-9]+[0-9]+"), ",", ".")))
```

[image]

#### EU syntax:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER({A1:A;B1:B;C1:C}; 
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*market*"; {A1:A;B1:B;C1:C}))); "[0-9]*\,[0-9]+[0-9]+")))
```

[image]

Comment: This caused a formula parse error for me. I modified it a bit to '=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER({A1:A;B1:B;C1:C}; 
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*market*"; {A1:A;B1:B;C1:C}))); "[0-9]*\,[0-9]+[0-9]+"); ";"; ".")))' but it removed commas and showed the value "3400".

Comment: so it works for you or still need further assistance?

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I still do need help unfortunately. What I need is 34,00 here, not 3400. When I format the cell as number or currency, it converts to 3400,00 but that's not what I need either.

Comment: @FOZDEMIR answer updated. try 2nd one

Comment: Second one kinda worked. Something interesting is happening here. When I change spreadsheet Locale settings to "UK" it works but writes "34.00". When I switch it back to "Turkey" it writes "34,00" when I make a change in one of the columns that contains text "market" it changes back to "3400" I'm confused now. I'm sharing the sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cb2yQyNungByP6sheijTWknjTwOR2POvMECjh2zUT64/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: well, yes. that's standard behaviour. UK uses `1.1` as number and turkey uses `1,1`. so depending on  what sheet locale you have you use either 1st syntax or 2nd one

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. The second one works perfectly. I closed all the browser tabs and when I opened the sheet back, it was just the way I wanted.